# Error when executing Camel marshall to CSV file

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I'm getting an error trying to run this camel route:

```
    <route>
      <from id="_from1" uri="timer:foo?repeatCount=1"/>
      <to id="_to3" uri="sql:select nro_servicio, documentodesconexionsap FROM servicio_cab;?dataSource=dataSource"/>
      <to id="_to2" uri="bean:com.enelint.pangeaent.GlobalDataController?method=processGlobalData(Exchange)"/>
      <marshal id="_marshal1">
       <csv/>
     </marshal>
     <to id="_to1" uri="file:/fs/out?fileName=out.csv"/>
    </route>
```

The stack trace is:  Error occurred while running main from: org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main.
If I change the marshal to string it creates the output file but obviously with the content not formatted as comma separated.
I'm using Camel version 2.17.
Any help will be appreciated.

UPDATE:
Here is my POJO class:

```
package com.enelint.pangeaenelint;

import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.annotation.CsvRecord;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.annotation.DataField;

@CsvRecord(separator="\\;")
public class ServicioCab {


    @DataField(pos=1, required=false)
    String documentodesconexionsap;

    @DataField(pos=2, required=false)
    String nro_cuenta_contrato;      

    @DataField(pos=3, required=false)
    String status;             

    @DataField(pos=4, required=true)
    String motivo_accion;           

    @DataField(pos=5, required=false, pattern="dd.MM.yyyy")
    String fecha_corte_repo;

    @DataField(pos=6, required=false)
    String hora_corte_repo;        

    @DataField(pos=7, required=false)
    String reemite;      

    @DataField(pos=8, required=false)
    String dias_reemision;             

    @DataField(pos=9, required=false)
    String enviado_sap;

    public String getDocumentodesconexionsap() {
        return documentodesconexionsap;
    }

    public void setDocumentodesconexionsap(String documentodesconexionsap) {
        this.documentodesconexionsap = documentodesconexionsap;
    }

    public String getNro_cuenta_contrato() {
        return nro_cuenta_contrato;
    }

    public void setNro_cuenta_contrato(String nro_cuenta_contrato) {
        this.nro_cuenta_contrato = nro_cuenta_contrato;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getMotivo_accion() {
        return motivo_accion;
    }

    public void setMotivo_accion(String motivo_accion) {
        this.motivo_accion = motivo_accion;
    }

    public String getFecha_corte_repo() {
        return fecha_corte_repo;
    }

    public void setFecha_corte_repo(String fecha_corte_repo) {
        this.fecha_corte_repo = fecha_corte_repo;
    }

    public String getHora_corte_repo() {
        return hora_corte_repo;
    }

    public void setHora_corte_repo(String hora_corte_repo) {
        this.hora_corte_repo = hora_corte_repo;
    }

    public String getReemite() {
        return reemite;
    }

    public void setReemite(String reemite) {
        this.reemite = reemite;
    }

    public String getDias_reemision() {
        return dias_reemision;
    }

    public void setDias_reemision(String dias_reemision) {
        this.dias_reemision = dias_reemision;
    }

    public String getEnviado_sap() {
        return enviado_sap;
    }

    public void setEnviado_sap(String enviado_sap) {
        this.enviado_sap = enviado_sap;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Could you post the entire stack trace? Also, do you have camel-bindy in your classpath? The POJO returned by your query are annotated by the Bindy annotations?

Comment: Hello Ricardo:
I do have camel-bindy in my POM; the class I'm returning in the query is declared in the following bean:
<bean class="org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.csv.BindyCsvDataFormat" id="bindyDataformatServicioCab">
   <argument value="com.enelint.pangeaenelintbase.ServicioCab"/>
</bean>
Anyway, I'm not declaring it in the ref property of the <marshal> tag. I also  tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Here is the stack trace:

http://textuploader.com/dq7u6

Comment: Are you using JBoss Fuse? Seems like it from the stacktrace. In that case you should refer to their support.

Comment: You can use Red Hat customer portal to get developer help with your JBoss Fuse product. However using stackoverflow with the jboss-fuse tag is also accepted, that is however just community help/support. Where as the latter is commercial help for fuse customers.

Comment: Make sure to have camel-sql on your classpath as well as you use the sql component

Comment: I'm using Jboss Fuse. I don't see the problem of asking questions in stackoverflow, anyway, I can use Eclipse if you prefer to run this project...And yes, I have camel-sql, the query works perfectly well: when I declare marshal - string in the route I get a string with the result of my query that is written to my output.csv file: [{nro_servicio=1, documentodesconexionsap=null, nro_cuenta_contrato=null, status=null, motivo_accion=null, fecha_corte_repo=null, hora_corte_repo=null, reemite=null, dias_reemision=null, enviado_sap=null, estado_transmision=P},...etc

Comment: @FranS. could you post your POJO class returned by your query (just edit your question with it)?

Comment: I just saw you return 2 fields from the query and then process it in `GlobalDataController` class. Could you post this class declaration (or at least the method `processGlobalData`)?

Comment: This is my camel route:
http://textuploader.com/dq2gv

And this is my class GlobalDataController:
http://textuploader.com/dq2gb

Finally, my POJO class:
http://textuploader.com/dq2g8

Thanks again.